# Calculating the enthalpy of polymerisation of ethylene given the bond strengths

Tags: thermodynamics, polymers, enthalpy

> Given the average bond dissociation enthalpies of a $\ce{C-C}$ bond (say $x$) and a $\ce{C=C}$ bond (say $y$), find the enthalpy of the following polymerisation reaction (per mole of ethylene):
>
> $$\ce{nCH_2=CH_2 -> [-CH2-CH2 -]_n}$$
>
> where $n$ is a large integer and $x, y$ are in $\pu{kJ/mol}$.

According to me, this should simply be $y-x$ as for every double bond broken, a single bond is formed. But the source book of this problem states the answer to be $y-2x$ claiming that for every double bond broken, **2 single bonds** are formed.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake I was making was not noticing that every time a double bond is **broken**, i.e.; completely broken, 2 single bonds are formed in its place.

One bond between the 2 carbons of the same molecule and another between two molecules, the former of which I forgot to consider.

Thus, the enthalpy is in fact $y-2x$

Comment: Then in that case, shouldn't there be 3 single bonds formed? 1 between the 2 Carbon atoms, then 2 more, formed at the free valencies; making the bond enthalpy $y-3x$